# Is the following truly a finite subcover?

Tags: real-analysis

For clarity, my textbook gives the following definition for a finite subcover:

> If $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. An **open cover** of $A$ is a collection $G
>  = \{G_\alpha\}$is a collection of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ whose union contains $A$; that is,
>
> $$A \subset \bigcup_{\alpha} G_\alpha$$
>
> If $G'$ is a subcollection of sets from $G$ such that the union of
>   sets in $G'$ also contains $A$, then $G'$ is called a **subcover** of
>   $G$. If $G'$ consists of finitely many sets, then we call $G'$ a
>   **finite subcover** of $G$.

The author goes on to provide examples of open covers of the set $A = [1, \infty)$. Two of which are

\begin{align}
B &= \{(r-1, r+1): r \in \mathbb{Q}, r>0\} \\
C &= \{(n-1, n+1): n \in \mathbb{N}\}
\end{align}

He goes on to note that, $C$ is a subcover of $B$. Nevermind, thought he said "finite" in the previous sentence. I'll count this as definition practice.

Comment: So you don't actually have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cover described(C) is not a finite subcover of B. In fact there does not exist a finite subcover since the set $[1,\infty)$ is unbounded. But the set is closed though.